# How can I optimize this mysql operation?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have this table - 'product-usage'. The columns in this table are id, rank, product_id, checked_at (timestamp). I am trying to add another column (timestamp) to this table called 'last_inactive' and retroactively fill that column. The logic for this is
1) Find created_at for the immediate next entry for same product_id (ordered by rank)
2) Take that timestamp and subtract 1 seconds and use that timestamp to fill the current column and go on
3) If the next row does not exist, use now() as the value for last_inactive

I have tried the following to get the desired result

```sql
SELECT *,
        coalesce(
date_sub(
(SELECT checked_at
              FROM product_usage p2
              WHERE p2.rank > p.rank
              and p.product_id=p2.product_id
              group by id, product_id, created_at
              ORDER BY product_id, rank ASC
              LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0),
INTERVAL 1 second),
now()
)
as valid_until
FROM product_usage p
where p.product_id = '1111111';
```

This query works for this particular product_id but it takes about 2-3 seconds per product_id and there are about 20k distinct product_ids I want this to work for. Is there anything I can do to make this faster?

Comment: Any query-optimization question should include the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE <tablename>` for the table(s) referenced by the query. Answers need to know what data types, indexes, and constraints you have in your table. Don't make us guess! Help us help you! And please post text, not screenshots.

Comment: That `group by` in your subquery seems out of place... and could cause some odd behavior unless id is the primary key of that table.

Comment: This is the old MySQL syntax (pre 5.7.5) that allowed weird grouping.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the aggregation in the subquery.  So try this:

```
SELECT pu.*,
       coalesce(date_sub( (SELECT pu2.checked_at
                           FROM product_usage pu2
                           WHERE pu2.rank > pu.rank AND
                                 pu2.product_id = pu.product_id
                           ORDER BY pu2.rank ASC
                           LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0
                          ), INTERVAL 1 second
                        ), now() ) as valid_until
FROM product_usage pu
WHERE pu.product_id = 1111111;  -- looks like a number so removed the single quotes
```

Then for this, you want an index on `product_usage(product_id, rank, created_at)`.

Of course, in MySQL 8+, you would just use `lead()`.